# matplotlib streamplot compresses the lines

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I'm struggling to plot streamlines using matplotlib1.2 but I noticed it compress the line spaces in y direction. My data in y direction is from 0.5-1.5 but the streamlines are plotted between 0.5-1.04. They looks correct and as I expect but I can not use them in my paper due to this compression. Is there way I can fix it? I bring the script I use below.

```
r=loadtxt('used_rad.dat')
r1=r[:-1]
Nr=256
Ns=512
dthet=2*pi/Ns
theta=arange(Ns)*dthet
vr=fromfile('gasvrad1000.dat')
vt=fromfile('gasvtheta1000.dat')
vr.resize(Nr,Ns)
vt.resize(Nr,Ns)
streamplot(theta,r1,vt,vr,density=3)
```

I can't post the image since I don't have enough reputation but if anyone needs to see the plot I can send it by email.

Comment: You could add a URL to the image, so someone with enough reputation can upload it to your post.

Comment: Post the image somewhere